# Weird "Retina" iOS simulator behavior

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, osx-mountain-lion

I updated Lion to Mountain Lion last week and since then, got this really weird bug on the iOS simulator. The first picture shows the regular simulator, and the second shows the "Retina" simulator. Does anyone know how to fix this? I tried deleting Xcode and re-installing, but had no luck.

Normal simulator:

[image: Normal simulator]

Retina simulator:

[image: Retina simulator]

Thanks for any help in advance!

Edit: This is not the iPad simulator. Here's a screenshot of the "Devices" menu.

[image: Devices Tab]

Comment: Not weird, this is your iphone app running on the iPad simulator

Comment: Try creating a new Xcode project. Run it on the retina simulator. Plus, update to Xcode 4.4 if you haven't. Ultimately, I laughed so hard at the pic, looks like a bug :)

Comment: Interesting. Try going to iOS Simulator menu and select "Reset Content and Settings". Maybe it will help

Comment: I have Xcode 4.4, so that can't be it. And "Reset Content and Settings" doesn't work either. So annoying!

Comment: Since the issue is not common, it might be very localized to your specific environment. Have you tried to reinstall Xcode 4.4 since updating to mountain lion? If not, try that.

Comment: what is Settings->General-About showing in simulator ? iPad or iPhone ? What is iOS SDK version ?

Comment: I'm sorry this is happening to you, but I'm glad it happened to someone. Now I know it isn't just me! I think this is some sort of bug in 4.4.

Comment: You better switch off to the command line :P

Comment: try resetting the content and settings of simulator or delete the derived data of the project in xcode organizer

Comment: Do you have a Retina MacBook Pro?

Comment: Is this just your app or springboard on the simulator too?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue, try changing the display resolution on your mac.  I am using a Retina Mac, so had to play around a bit.

Xcode did give you a different simulator for retina, but looks like they built in the logic to have higher resolution in one simluator.

Comment: I recently experienced this problem and can confirm in my case was not related to my project code. Depending on the screen resolution you have your simulator in, it will serve up different UI. I.E. 1. In my Thunderbolt display it showed iPad like border interface for iPhone (Retina 4-inch). 2. In my Retina Macbook Pro screen, the same setting will show an iPhone 5like interface. Note: I had to change device version to another to see the affected change in the other display.

Answer (score 0):

The most important symptom here is that your UI is occupying exactly the the amount of space you would expect if it was displaying to a standard resolution iPhone.  And the other important symptom is the way your UILabels are looking washed out - that's often a sign that the UILabel is not receiving the correct scale for the screen, especially if rasterizing.

When you're initializing your app in your app delegate (didFinishLaunchingWithOptions) check to see if you have hard coded the bounds for either the UIWindow or the rootViewController for your UIWindow to standard iphone resolution (i.e. 320x480).  Those should be set using [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds] instead of being hard-coded to actual points.  Indeed, you should be looking for any place in your app where you have hard coded the screen dimensions - do a search for the string "320" and "480" - those are numbers that should never appear in your code.

The other possibility is that you've set some of your views to rasterize (layer.shouldRasterize = YES) but you have not set layer.rasterizationScale to the scale of the main screen (i.e. [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale], which will be 2.0 in the Retina context).    I've seen the same sort of muddy UILabel's when I've not set the scale properly.

I recognize that since your post says that this change only occurred since your OS update, these are probably not the issues, but just to be extra-sure, I would check them.

**Update**: On second thought, hard coding those bounds, which bad practice, could not cause this problem, since those are the correct logical bounds for iPhone, and the OS scales for you.  So between those two suggestions, the more likely culprit is that some scale related property is getting set incorrectly.  Another possibility is if you're using the UIView contentScaleFactor and setting it incorrectly.

Answer (score -3):

This is iPAd simulator. Change it to iPhone.

> Hardware->Device